# Find first occurrence and update using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below data, I want to find out first occurrence of pay begin and pay end date for each start and end date and mark it as processed. How do I find the row and write and UPDATE sql?

Actual Table

```
ID    Start Date     End Date       Pay Begin     Pay End Date    Processed     
123   01/01/2022     01/30/2022     01/01/2023     01/14/2023        N 
123   01/01/2022     01/30/2022     01/01/2023     01/14/2023        N 
123   02/01/2022     03/30/2022     03/01/2023     03/14/2023        N       
123   02/01/2022     03/30/2022     03/01/2023     03/14/2023        N       
123   05/01/2022     05/30/2022     05/01/2023     05/14/2023        N
```

Expected Results

```
ID    Start Date     End Date       Pay Begin     Pay End Date    Processed     
123   01/01/2022     01/30/2022     01/01/2023     01/14/2023        Y 
123   01/01/2022     01/30/2022     01/01/2023     01/14/2023        N 
123   02/01/2022     03/30/2022     03/01/2023     03/14/2023        Y       
123   02/01/2022     03/30/2022     03/01/2023     03/14/2023        N       
123   05/01/2022     05/30/2022     05/01/2023     05/14/2023        Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated sub-query (correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column) and the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to find the first row in each partition:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET   processed = 'Y'
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY id, start_date, end_date
             ORDER BY pay_begin, pay_end_date
           ) AS rn
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Start_Date, End_Date, Pay_Begin, Pay_End_Date, Processed ) AS
SELECT 123, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-30', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-14', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-30', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-14', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, DATE '2022-02-01', DATE '2022-03-30', DATE '2023-03-01', DATE '2023-03-14', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, DATE '2022-02-01', DATE '2022-03-30', DATE '2023-03-01', DATE '2023-03-14', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, DATE '2022-05-01', DATE '2022-05-30', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-05-14', 'N' FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `UPDATE`, the table contains:

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | PAY_BEGIN | PAY_END_DATE | PROCESSED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-30 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-14 00:00:00 | Y |
| 123 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-30 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-14 00:00:00 | N |
| 123 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2022-03-30 00:00:00 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | Y |
| 123 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2022-03-30 00:00:00 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | N |
| 123 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 2022-05-30 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-14 00:00:00 | Y |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4vIXzkqm)